# create csv file from not equal length list of list of sports games

Tags: python, csv

I have list of lists of sports matches:

```
table = [['Volleyball', ' Europe', 'European Championships', 'Today 17:00', 'Moldova - Cyprus', '2.00', '1.72'],
['Handball', ' Slovenia', '1. NLB Liga', 'Today 17:00', 'Krka - Slovenj Gradec', '2.05', '1.98'],
['American Football', ' USA', 'NCAA', 'Today 17:00', 'Marshall - Eastern Kentucky', '1.90', '1.90', 'Today 20:00', 'Army - Middle Tennessee St', '2.01', '1.99', 'Tomorrow 20:00', 'West Virginia - Florida State', '2.50', '1.50'],
['Soccer', ' World', 'Club Friendly', 'Today 17:00', 'UE Sants (Esp) - CE Europa (Esp)', '1.84', '1.88', 'Today 17:00', 'Spain - France', '1.20', '2.80'],
['Tennis', ' USA', 'ATP US Open', 'Today 17:30', 'Berrettini M. - Ruud C.', '1.81', '2.02']]
```

columns are:

```
sport  country  competition  date  match  odd_1  odd_2
```

In each nested list, first 3 elements are always : `sport,  country,  competition`.
After those 3 first elements, come `date  match  odd_1  odd_2`, one time or more than one time (means each nested list can have many matches, in the same sport and one competition)

I want to create the csv from this data, but some nested lists contains more than one match:

```
with open(filename.csv, 'a', encoding='utf_8_sig') as csv_file: 
    w = csv.writer(csv_file, lineterminator='\n')
    header = 
    w.writerow(header)

    for row in table:
        w.writerow(row)
```

Comment: The length of the lists, does not match the number of of columns

Comment: yes, each list has one match or more than one match

Comment: Each list should be one record.

Comment: Please provide your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK all the csv handling libraries expect a constant number of elements on each row of the csv file. Therefore, even if you split the rows as is, it will not be a proper csv with different number of elements in each row.

If you are fine with having the `[date, match, odd1, odd2 ...]` list as a single element in the csv, you can do this as follows (You will need to split the data of that column when you load the csv of cource)

```
#python3
import csv

with open('filename.csv', 'w') as fp:
    dr = csv.DictWriter(fp, ['sport', 'country', 'competition', 'matches'])
    dr.writeheader()
    for row in table: 
        sport,  country,  competition, *rest = row
        dr.writerow({'sport': sport, 'country': country, 'competition': competition, 'matches': rest})
```

You can read the csv as follows

```
with open('data.csv') as fp:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fp)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['sport'], row['matches'])
```

However, now `row['matches']` will be a `string` (not a `list`) and therefore you have to convert into the list again if you want to access separate data

You can use `ast` module for `string->list` conversion. However, I would suggest looking into pickling or any other representation for this kind of data (depending on your use case of course)

```
import ast
with open('data.csv') as fp:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fp)
    for row in reader:
        print(ast.literal_eval(row['matches']))  # Prints the list not str
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure out a way to slice the list using more_itertools:

```
rows = []
for i in table:
    if len(i) == 12:
        row = i[:7]+i[-2:]
        rows.append(row)
    if len(i) > 12:
        m = i[:3]
        n = i[3:]
        n_list = list(more_itertools.chunked(n, 7))
        for k in n_list:
            row = m + k
            rows.append(row)
```

It work very well